# HTML on fusion chart Caption and subcaption

Tags: javascript, jquery, fusioncharts

I have been trying to add `HTML` tags and Character to **fusion chart** `Caption` and `subCaption` but was unable to execute.

I have tried the method in this **[documentation link](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/common-use-cases/using-special-characters-in-a-chart)** and also tried an **[old one](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/advanced/special-chars/SpPunctuation.html)** but it also doesn't work.

```js
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var salesChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: 'column2d',
      renderAt: 'chart-container',
      width: '500',
      height: '300',
      dataFormat: 'json',
      dataSource: {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "&quot;Quarterly Revenue",
          "subCaption": "&amp;lt;span&amp;gt; Last year &amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;",
          "xAxisName": "Quarter",
          "yAxisName": "Amount (In USD)",
          "numberPrefix": "$",
          //Caption cosmetics 
          "captionFont": "Arial",
          "captionFontSize": "18",
          "captionFontColor": "#993300",
          "captionFontBold": "1",
          "subcaptionFont": "Arial",
          "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
          "subcaptionFontColor": "#993300",
          "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
          //Theme
          "theme": "fusion"
        },
        "data": [{
          "label": "&quot;Q1",
          "value": "1950000"
        }, {
          "label": "&quot; Q2",
          "value": "1450000"
        }, {
          "label": "Q3",
          "value": "1730000"
        }, {
          "label": "Q4",
          "value": "2120000"
        }]
      }
    })
    .render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>



<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of (without messing with the source too much) is to attach an event handler and adding your HTML.

Here is how I planned it:

1. When Captions are rendered fire an evevnt - `rendered`
2. Get the position of the subcaption from the calculated element.
3. Create `foreignObject` to store and append your HTML.
4. Use the chart options to fill the HTML content and some other quick settings:

Here is the code (its quick and dirty but it does the job :)

[**JSFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/6a0wu5sg/1/)

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
      var salesChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: 'column2d',
      renderAt: 'chart-container',
      // Attach event handlers
      events: {
        // Attach to beforeRender
        "rendered": function(eventObj, argsObj) {
          console.log(this);
          let $caption = $(eventObj.sender.container).find("g[class$=-caption]");
          let $subcaption = $caption.find("text").eq(1);
          //Create a foreign element - that will render inside SVG:
          let foreign = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "foreignObject");
          //Html subCaption is derived from the options:
          let subCaption = $(this.args.dataSource.chart.subCaption);
          //Set foreign attributes - should be set forceCaptionAttr: 
          foreign.setAttribute("x", $subcaption.attr("x"));
          foreign.setAttribute("y", $subcaption.attr("y"));
          foreign.setAttribute("style", $subcaption.attr("style"));
          $.each(this.args.dataSource.chart.forceCaptionAttr, function(key, value) {
            switch (key) {
              case "offsetX":
                foreign.setAttribute("x", parseInt($subcaption.attr("x")) + value);
                break;
              case "offsetY":
                foreign.setAttribute("y", parseInt($subcaption.attr("y")) + value);
                break;
              default:
                foreign.setAttribute(key, value);
                break;
            }

          });
          //Remove SVG text element:
          $subcaption.remove();
          //Append the subcaption to foreign:
          foreign.appendChild(subCaption[0]);
          //Append to Caption svg container:
          $caption[0].appendChild(foreign);
        }
      },
      width: '500',
      height: '300',
      dataFormat: 'json',
      dataSource: {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "\"Quarterly Revenue\"",
          "subCaption": "<strong>I'm Displaying HTML in SVG &#128540;</strong></span>",
          // the intial values are taken from the text svg -> this wil change the values so u can fix some positioning issues:
          "forceCaptionAttr": {
            offsetX: -100,
            offsetY: -10,
            width: 250,
            height: 30
          },
          "xAxisName": "Quarter",
          "yAxisName": "Amount (In USD)",
          "numberPrefix": "$",
          "captionFont": "Arial",
          "captionFontSize": "18",
          "captionFontColor": "#993300",
          "captionFontBold": "1",
          "subcaptionFont": "Arial",
          "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
          "subcaptionFontColor": "#fff",
          "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
          "theme": "fusion"
        },
        "data": [{
            "label": "\"Q1\"",
            "value": "1950000"
          },
          {
            "label": "\"Q2\"",
            "value": "1450000"
          },
          {
            "label": "\"Q3\"",
            "value": "1730000"
          },
          {
            "label": "\"Q4\"",
            "value": "2120000"
          }
        ]
      }
    })
    .render();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `caption` and `subcaption` are treated as `string`.

Please look into the sample below. Hope this is your desired output -

```js
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var salesChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: 'column2d',
      renderAt: 'chart-container',
      width: '500',
      height: '300',
      dataFormat: 'json',
      dataSource: {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "\"Quarterly Revenue\"",
          "subCaption": "<span>Last year</span>",
          "xAxisName": "Quarter",
          "yAxisName": "Amount (In USD)",
          "numberPrefix": "$",
          "captionFont": "Arial",
          "captionFontSize": "18",
          "captionFontColor": "#993300",
          "captionFontBold": "1",
          "subcaptionFont": "Arial",
          "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
          "subcaptionFontColor": "#993300",
          "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
          "theme": "fusion"
        },
        "data": [
          {
            "label": "\"Q1\"",
            "value": "1950000"
          },
          {
            "label": "\"Q2\"",
            "value": "1450000"
          },
          {
            "label": "\"Q3\"",
            "value": "1730000"
          },
          {
            "label": "\"Q4\"",
            "value": "2120000"
          }
        ]
      }
    })
    .render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>



<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but no, I want the `HTML` to be converted. I need that to be an element not a text like your sample.

Comment: @weBBer The texts here in caption and subcaption are rendered as "SVG" text elements and not "HTML" elements. Thus, I think it is not achievable right now.

Comment: `<tspan>` will work inside text in SVG but still it's not working in this case, I need a way to create it.